# Facing problem in installing the os and random, sys, subprocess, multiprocessing packages in Python using VS code

Tags: python, package

I am trying to install the libraries 'os', 'getopt', 'multiprocessing', 'subprocess', 'sys', and 'random' in Python 3.12.0 but facing a problem in installing these libraries. Here is the error during installing 'os' using "pip install os";

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for os
```

**Note:** I already tried to restart the kernel but it doesn't work. I tried to restart my laptop as well. I also tried to install using Anaconda but did not succeed.

I tried to reinstall these packages several times but in vain. Is there any other ways to get these packages?

Comment: Those packages are part of standard python and there is no need to install them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This packages come with python by default. You don't need to install them. They are already installed. You can check by importing them to a python file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).